# Full desktop size in vmWare workstation

Tags: linux, vmware, linux-mint, vmware-workstation

I have installed Linux mint in vmWare.

The problem I have is that the desktop are not in full size. Take a look at the picture, and you can see what I mean.

[image: vmware]

How can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enter into the full desktop view of the guest OS(Linux Mint), you need to press **`Ctrl + Alt + Enter`**.

This will get you into the full-screen mode of guest OS,Linux Mint here. Also, to return back to the host OS(Windows 7), press **`Alt + Enter`** and the pointer(cursor) will be free to move outside the VMware boundary.

***EDIT :-***

As the old answer didn't work, I suggest you to edit virtual machine settings of the Linux Mint OS. As you can see from the image,click on the **`"Edit Virtual Machine Settings"`** on the left. It will open a new window "Virtual Machine Settings". Here, as shown in the below image,for my Windows 7 x64 guest OS here(yours should be Linux Mint OS), go to "Power" under Options menu and edit the information as I have done here.

Also, go to `View` --> `Autosize` --> `Stretch Guest` and select that. Please do ensure that `View` --> `Full Screen` is also enabled.

[image: Full Screen View in VMware Workstation.]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it did not work.The Linux Mint desktop is exactly the same as in the above.

Comment: @Bryan-Please don't forget to upvote the answer. You please try once again,here's the link --- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow